# How to display it out without using the Mouse to highlight it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Here is my designer code

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    </br>Product Name:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductName") %>
                    </br>Quantity:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Content>
```

When I run the program, the repeater details like product name and Quantity details will hidden it and only display when I use the mouse to highlight it.

Comment: Do you have any CSS for the repeater? Also, you have the slash in the wrong part of the `<br>`, it should be `<br/>`.

Comment: After I change it to <br/> also same. I do not have any CSS for the repeater.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the hidden repeater details like product name and quantity details?

Comment: Due to my reputation is below 10 so this websites not allow me to post the screenshot.

Comment: Okay, you are over 10 now, please post a screenshot.

Comment: What is making the background black? Browser setting or CSS?

Comment: This is I Set the CSS For body part but I didn't set the CSS for Repeater.

Comment: When you set the background to black, do you set the foreground to white or another color that is clearly visible on a black background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the background color of the body of the HTML document, then the repeater is just inserting text on top of that background, thus it is inheriting the background color of the body.

To control the background color of the `Product Name` and `Quantity`, put them inside of ASP.NET `Label` controls and then use `CssClass` to control their background color, like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <br/>
    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="WhiteBackground" 
        Text="Product Name: " />
    <asp:Label id="LabelProductName" runat="server" CssClass="WhiteBackground"
        Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductName") %>' />
    <br/>
    <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="WhiteBackground" 
        Text="Quantity: " />
    <asp:Label id="LabelQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="WhiteBackground"
        Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity") %>'
</ItemTemplate>
```

CSS:

```
.WhiteBackground {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate for help. Thanks

Comment: @Michael - it is generally frowned upon to piggyback questions on here. I would suggest taking the solution you have and updating your code in a new question. It makes it clear the question and answer here  stands alone. You can make reference to this question in your new question.